# Getting blank output in pytest for my code, not sure how to resolve this

Tags: python, pytest

In part 1, there are 3 variables (attack, defense and hp). If attack is less than or equal to defense, that means no damage is done. However, if attack is greater than defense, damage is done.

```
# part 1
def main():
    defense = 5
    attack = 8
    hp = 10

    if attack <= defense:
        return 'No damage, since the defense stat is too high.'
    
    if attack > defense:
       damage = attack - defense
       hp = hp - damage
       return f'{damage} damage inflicted, enemy HP is now {hp}.'

print(main())
```

In part 2 of my code, there is a list of pet names. My code counts the amount of names in the list and the lengths of each word in the list.

```
# part 2
pets = ['Spot', 'Boots', 'Mrs. Fluffington', 'Lenny', 'Bowser', 'Gina']
count = 0
word_lengths = []

def list_count(pets):
    count = 0
    for names in pets:
        count += 1
    return count

print(f'There are {list_count(pets)} pets in the list.')

def length_counter():
    x = 0
    while x < list_count(pets):
        length = 0
        for character in pets[x]:
            length += 1
        word_lengths.append(length)
        x += 1
    return f'The word lengths of each word are {word_lengths}.'
print(length_counter())
```

I've added an image link to my pytest results below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJvMo.png)

(UPDATED) Pytest in Text:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1237]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(base) C:\Users\aksha>cd C:\Users\aksha\lab-02-akshayanbalathas

(base) C:\Users\aksha\lab-02-akshayanbalathas>pytest --capture=sys
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.8, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\aksha\lab-02-akshayanbalathas
plugins: anyio-2.2.0
collected 1 item

lab02_test.py F                                                          [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_main __________________________________

capsys = <_pytest.capture.CaptureFixture object at 0x0000016FF996D670>

    def test_main(capsys):
        lab02.main() # run the student's code
        captured = capsys.readouterr()
        sys.stderr.write('actual output:\n')
        sys.stderr.write(captured.out + '\n')
        correct_output = '3 damage inflicted, enemy HP is now 7.\nThere are 6 pets in the list.\nThe word lengths of each word are [4, 5, 16, 5, 6, 4].\n'

        sys.stderr.write('correct output:\n')
        sys.stderr.write(correct_output + '\n')
>       assert captured.out == correct_output # verify that the output is a match
E       AssertionError: assert '3 damage inf...16, 5, 6, 4].' == '3 damage inf..., 5, 6, 4].\n'
E         Skipping 112 identical leading characters in diff, use -v to show
E         - , 5, 6, 4].
E         ?            -
E         + , 5, 6, 4].

lab02_test.py:14: AssertionError
---------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
actual output:
3 damage inflicted, enemy HP is now 7.
There are 6 pets in the list.
The word lengths of each word are [4, 5, 16, 5, 6, 4].
correct output:
3 damage inflicted, enemy HP is now 7.
There are 6 pets in the list.
The word lengths of each word are [4, 5, 16, 5, 6, 4].

============================== warnings summary ===============================
..\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py:8
  C:\Users\aksha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.9 it will stop working
    return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
FAILED lab02_test.py::test_main - AssertionError: assert '3 damage inf...16, ...
======================== 1 failed, 1 warning in 0.39s =========================

(base) C:\Users\aksha\lab-02-akshayanbalathas>
```

Comment: You mentioned pytest and its output. How does your test look like?

Comment: @trivvz I've added an image link to my pytest at the bottom of my code now

Comment: screenshot is good, but could you also add the test code as text? It's easier to work with it this way ;]

Comment: @trivvz I've added it in text now :)

Comment: @trivvz thank you for your help thus far I've updated my pytest text above

Comment: Ok, sure. I made a mistake in copying your test code. I updated my answer, it should work now

Comment: yes, it is working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as you can see in the test code:

```py
def test_main(capsys):
        lab02.main() # run the student's code
```

It calls your `main()` function, so all the printing should be done within that function rather than in global scope. At this point, all your code outside `main()` is ignored by the test.

I changed your code slightly, and now it passes the test:

```py
# part 1
def main():
    defense = 5
    attack = 8
    hp = 10

    if attack <= defense:
        print('No damage, since the defense stat is too high.')
    
    if attack > defense:
       damage = attack - defense
       hp = hp - damage
       print(f'{damage} damage inflicted, enemy HP is now {hp}.')

    # part 2
    pets = ['Spot', 'Boots', 'Mrs. Fluffington', 'Lenny', 'Bowser', 'Gina']
    count = 0
    word_lengths = []

    def list_count(pets):
        count = 0
        for names in pets:
            count += 1
        return count

    print(f'There are {list_count(pets)} pets in the list.')

    def length_counter():
        x = 0
        while x < list_count(pets):
            length = 0
            for character in pets[x]:
                length += 1
            word_lengths.append(length)
            x += 1
        return f'The word lengths of each word are {word_lengths}.'
    print(length_counter())
```

I just changed the first two `return` to `print()` in your `main()` and moved the rest of your code inside `main()`. Feel free to refactor it as you wish ;] If I were you, I would move all functions definitions outside `main()`, and just call them from it. It's a common and good practice. The functions should return `str` and `main()` should print the output.

Let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: The outputs now match in my pytest as well , but I am still getting a failed pytest. Would you like me to update the pytest text?

Comment: @Akshayan416, I got it, there is a newline at the end of test expected output. Please remove `end=""` from the last line of main function. I'll update my answer.

Comment: yess pytest has passed the code, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Akshayan416, you're welcome :) Would you mind to mark the answer as correct, to mark your question as resolved?